# How to display data from a file on website load?

Tags: html, css, file, web

So I have a file that's already constantly being update on my server, but the directory currently isn't in my wwwroot folder until I can actually meddle around in there to get the directory to change.

So question #1 is if it's possible for my site to actually access this file away from the wwwroot? If not, it's okay. I'll find some way to get it in there.

This is however the more important part of this question. The file in question is currently in .data extension and contains a field such as {"cpu":30,"ram":300000}. It's been updated in real time with an application in the background, but how would I get my web page to pull those data and display it? I only started learning HTML and CSS several days ago, so my knowledge is still pretty limited here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand your first question. :S Please, could you be more clear?

For the second one, to read the text file you need a javascript code. You can do that as follow:

1º Open the file: `file = fopen(getScriptPath("myFile.txt"), 0);`
2º Get the content of the file in a string: `file_length = flength(file); content = fread(file, file_length);`
3º Finally, you can get the part of the string you want by a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling data from external sources and displaying it in HTML is a very common practice the purpose of programming languages like PHP. You aren't going to be able to do it with just HTML/CSS. Stick to static (unchanging) pages until you've got HTML/CSS down, and then you can learn a scripting language to make dynamic pages.